# How to define the value type for example

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Example:

```js
type ObjProps = {
  a: string;
  b: string[] | null;
};

type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];

const obj: ObjProps = {
  a: 'test',
  b: null
};

type ParamsProps = {
  propName: keyof ObjProps;
  value: ValueOf<ObjProps>;
}

const updateFn = ({
 propName, 
 value
}: ParamsProps): void => {
  obj[propName] = value; // ts error
}
```

for this example, how to define ParamsProps correctly?

expect to the right way and editor auto prompt the type only can be string.

```js
updateFn({
  propName: 'a',
  value: 'update' // editor auto prompt the type only can be string
});
```

Will someone help me?

[Exapmle TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKwAoCcD2YDOUC8UDeAUFFAIYBcUmwKAlgHYDmA3MVHJdXUwNoC6UAD5R6AVwA241gF9WhUJCgA1UuNEQYAMwA8AFQB8uKLp4BrCCDSbjfOQGM09alDSJK8ZOixGiJClAByYAhqAIAaNg4RCXFCWUJ5cGgkUhRSAFtMVAxsPF8oMC8AOQyISnNLaw9srFYSADdVdUoVNQ0daq9MfRkEhydgKFEwABNSYI8jAApfQowS9IgwqGJGtrjKFLTMmswASkp6tFoR3EN81wQeObAFiAE8NfVmKAB6V6hgbAgUdBQ4oA)

Comment: Your `ParamsProps` is not properly distributed, but even if you fix that you still can't write `updateFn()`'s implementation without an error unless you make `updateFn` *generic*.  Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/m0y7DW) work for you? If so I can maybe write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in doubt, add more generics!

```
type ObjProps = {
  a: string;
  b: string[] | null;
};

const obj: ObjProps = {
  a: 'test',
  b: null
};

type ParamsProps<TKey extends keyof ObjProps> = {
  propName: TKey;
  value: ObjProps[TKey];
}

const updateFn = <TKey extends keyof ObjProps>({ propName, value }: ParamsProps<TKey>): void => {
  obj[propName] = value;
}

updateFn({propName: 'a', value: "test"});
updateFn({propName: 'b', value: ["test"]});
updateFn({propName: 'b', value: null});
updateFn({propName: 'a', value: ["test"]}); // ts error
```

Comment: I see @jcalz long beat me to the answer as a comment though